# Gets related problem

Tags: objective-c, c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
   FILE * pFile;
   int n;
   char name [100];

   pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt", "w");
   for (n = 0; n < 3; n++)
   {
     puts ("please, enter a name: ");
     gets (name);
     fprintf (pFile, "Name %d [%-10.10s]\n", n, name);
   }
   fclose (pFile);

   return 0;
}
```

this code gives me a warning in gcc saying 'gets is a dangerous function to use'...is there a workaround for it?

Comment: This doesn't look like an Objective-C question in particular... What's your intent?

Comment: Consider this:  what happens if I put in a name that's longer than 100 characters?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is `fgets`. Replace your call to `gets` with:

```
fgets(name, 100, stdin)
```

For more details see the docs - the two are not exactly the same.